# how to disappear an animated gif with javascript

Tags: javascript, counter, animated-gif

i have this code and would like to have an animated gif to disappear after 3 seconds. i learned that i need to add window.onload=loadingGif(); to ensure the 'loadingGif' function is fired when the page loads. i stll have the problem that this code is not working how it should do. i would like to know what is going wrong with that? thanks.

i´m sorry i posted the wrong code. it must be:

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 3;                              
function downcount() {
  document.getElementById('digit').firstChild.nodeValue = counter ;
  if (counter == 0 ) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('msg').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    counter--;
    window.setTimeout('downcount()', 1000);
  }
}
window.onload=downcount;
</script>

<div id="loading">
  <img src="loading/loading40.gif"/>
</div>

<div id="msg" style="display:none">
   <?PHP echo $_SESSION['msg'];?>
</div>
```

Comment: `something.style=display:none;` is not valid JavaScript. You are heavily mixing plain JavaScript and jQuery. I'd suggest to decide for one of the them. It would make your code more consistent and easier to read. `window.onload=loadingGif();` will assign the *return value* of `loadingGif` to `window.onload`, not the function itself. I recommend to revise some JavaScript basics.

Comment: "How to disappear something" - reminds me of Catch 22 and their characters wondering what does it mean to "disappear someone" ;)

Comment: But in all seriousness, you have a lot of syntax errors and mistakes in your code. Rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript animated gif forwarding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597788/javascript-animated-gif-forwarding) -- please don't ask questions twice. If none of the answers in your previous question helped you, then don't accept any. Wait until you get a proper answer and new information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Close the img tag.

Also, where's digit? If that doesn't exist then you'll be getting JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing three 1s setTimeout to wait for 3 seconds? Here is a simpler solution, right out of my head...

```
window.onload = setTimeout(removeImg, 3000)
var removeImg = function() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('msg').style.display = 'block'
}
```